# Pin the dock in macOS to the top of the screen

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

System preferences -> Dock let's me configure the Dock to be placed wither left, bottom or right. Is there a way to place it top instead?

Answer (score 0):

No. It would interfere with the menu bar.